# Is there any better way to show success alert message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show **Success message** , once the data is updated in my application. `Success function` is working properly , but message is not getting generated. when I click on the `save()` button, small alert box will display, but message wont appear.

HTML : `<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="successmessage">{{cts.success_info}}</div>`

Angular Js:

```
$scope.successmessage = function(){ 
   $scope.cts = [];
   $scope.cts.success_info = "Data Successfully got updated"; 
 }
```

Comment: Use `ng-show="success_info"`

Comment: You defined `successmessage` as a function, but using as a value. Besides of this it must return a boolean value.

Comment: @alexmac. once i tried in boolean type also. But again , my message din't got displayed

Answer (score 1):

You defined `successmessage` as a function, but using it as a value.
If you need to display alert on success call of `save` function, use `success` function below. It creates an object with a message and `isSuccess` flag:

Html:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="cts.isSuccess">{{ cts.message }}</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.success = function() { 
  $scope.cts = {
    isSuccess: true,
    message: 'Data Successfully got updated'
  }; 
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/js7bjz5r/2/)

Comment: You need to call `success` function from you `save` function, because you mentioned that _when I click on the save() button, small alert box will display, but message wont appear_.

Comment: yea. I called it through `success` function itself . But it din't work

Comment: Check my answer again, it was mistake in `ng-show="cts.isSuccess"`, I called `cts.isSuccess` as a function, when it's a field.

Comment: only i could see the alert box. But message is not getting generated

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, I've created a working demo, and here it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of *ngIf if want to display more then just simple string like below:

```
showMsg: boolean = false;

onSubmit() {
this.userService.createUser(this.addForm.value)
  .subscribe( data => {
    this.router.navigate(['list-user']);
    this.showMsg= true;
  });
}
then you can use showMsg boolean to show/hide dive like below

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div ng-click=="onSubmit()">

   <div class="row"  *ngIf="showMsg">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <p class="alert alert-success">
             <strong>Registration Success!</strong> Please click here to login!.

         </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success">Add user</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

note that I am using some bootstrap classes for styling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes function must return something . If you want a better option , you can use **toast** or **popover** .

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

`<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show='cts.showmsg == true'>{{cts.success_info}}</div>`

You can use one boolean variable to show/hide message.

Angular Js:

```
$scope.successmessage = function(){ 
   $scope.cts = [];
   $scope.cts.success_info = "Data Successfully got updated";
   $scope.cts.showmsg = true;
 }
```

Comment: just now i implemented your function. But message dint got displayed @kaustubh

Comment: @kishore reason behind that is, function does not return.

Comment: yea. your wright. But just now i implemented your code. But its not displaying anything and any error also

Comment: @kishore added boolean variable `showmsg` use that one.

Comment: @kishore inspect you html code. I think your css is not right.

Comment: Html code is right. But there is some mistake in your code

Comment: where have you defined `successmessage` function

Comment: @kishore call `successmessage()` from `successcallback` function after `save()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155073/discussion-between-kaustubh-khare-and-kishore).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display in popup or modal, then there is best library in angular called [**ngDialog**](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)